# Getter Setter between two Visualforce pages

Tags: apex, visualforce, getter, setter

I am confused how to use to getter setter in the situation of two Visualforce pages having different extensions.

1 VF Page(Main Page): This page calls Opportunity as Standard Controller and having two Extensions = Ext1, Ext2. I have a inputTextArea field where it has a lookup. On the click of the Lookup page(Second VF Page - LookupPage) user search for Employee records(custom object having SF and Non SF user list) and select multiple employees through a checkbox. On the click of the OK button in the lookup page it does gets all the Employee Names through Ext2. Till this point I am fine but I am confused how to retain the EmployeeNames from Ext2 and populate in the InputTextArea field which is on the First Page?

**Page 1**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="Ext1,Ext2" tabStyle="Opportunity" >
<apex:form id="form_Upload">
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Email Recipients" columns="2">
                <apex:inputHidden value="{!allSelectedEmpIds}" id="targetId" />
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Email To List" for="ToList"/>
                    <apex:outputPanel >
                        <apex:inputTextarea id="empNames" value="{!empName}" onfocus="this.blur()" disabled="false"/><a href="#" onclick="openLookupPopup(); return false">Lookup</a>---This is place where I want to get the Employee Names--
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Extension**

```
public class Ext1{

    public String emailToList {get;set;}
    public String emailCcList {get;set;}
    public String emailBccList {get;set;}
    private final Opportunity opp {get;set;} 


    public Ext1(ApexPages.StandardController standardController) {
         this.opp = (Opportunity)standardController.getRecord();    
    }}

    public with sharing class Ext2{   public List<employeeWrapper> employeeList {get;set;}
    public String allSelectedEmpIds{get;set;}
    public String empName{get;set;} // This is the one I want to return to Main Page
    public boolean canLookup {get;set;}
    public String searchString{get;set;}
    private final Opportunity opp;
public void processSelected(){
        //PageReference np;
        allSelectedEmpIds = '';
        empName = '';
        for (employeeWrapper eEmp: employeeList) {
            System.debug('checkbox selected'+ eEmp.isSelected);
            if(eEmp.isSelected){
                allSelectedEmpIds += ';'+eEmp.employee.Id;
                empName += ';'+eEmp.employee.FullName__c;
            }/*else{
                allSelectedEmpIds += ';'+eEmp.employee.Id;
            } */

        }
}
```

**Page 2**

```
<apex:page id="employeeLookupPage" controller="Ext2" showHeader="false">
<apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Employee List" id="employeblock">
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="Section" showheader="false" columns="1">
                <!--apex:pageblocksectionitem id="SectionItem" >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="First Name or Last Name Search" for="searchStringPanel" style="font-weight:Bold;padding-right:10px;" />
                    <apex:outputPanel id="searchStringPanel"-->
                        <apex:inputText id="srchString" value="{!searchString}"/>
                        <apex:commandButton title="Go!" value="Go!" reRender="employeePanel" action="{!search}"/>
                    <!--/apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageblocksectionitem-->
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:outputPanel id="employeePanel">
                <apex:pageBlock id="employeeBlock">
                    <apex:inputHidden value="{!allSelectedEmpIds}" id="targetId" />
                    <apex:inputHidden value="{!empName}" id="namefield" />
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!employeeList}" var="empNames">
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!e.isSelected}" id="selectedEmp"/>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column id="fname" >
                            <apex:facet name="header">First Name</apex:facet>
                            <apex:outputText value="{!e.employee.First_Name__c}"/>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Last Name">
                            <apex:outputText value="{!e.employee.Last_Name__c}"/>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Email">
                            <apex:outputText value="{!e.employee.Email__c}"/>
                        </apex:column>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:pageBlock>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <div align="Right" draggable="false">
                    <apex:commandButton value="Ok" action="{!processSelected}" />
                    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="window.top.close()" />
                </div>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: can you post your Ex2 class

Answer (score 0):

To create an StandardController extension you need to define constructor with StanardController as an argument.

```
public Ext2(ApexPages.StandardController standardController) {
         this.opp = (Opportunity)standardController.getRecord();    
    }
```

2nd thing, after closing the popup window, I think you are not refreshing the calling page, that's why it is not taking `empNames` and you are preparing those concatenated values on server side.

So you need to rerender page with `"form_Upload"` to retrieve updated values.